# Fetch Top 2000 Records

Tags: ms-access

I have following query:

```
strfinal = "
    TRANSFORM Format(Sum([Mandays].[Hours]),""#0.0"") AS [The Value] 
    SELECT 
        Mandays.WorkTypeCode AS WONo, 
        Format(Sum([Mandays].[Hours]),""0000.0"") AS Total 
    FROM Mandays 
    GROUP BY Mandays.WorkTypeCode 
    PIVOT UCase([Ent By]); "
```

The query returns more than 2048 records so it is not possible to show in VB6 MSHFLexGrid (limit is 2048). How do I **change the query so that top 2000 records** are fetched?

Comment: can any one correct the query?